# Changing string to an existing variable name to create 1 function for multiple variables (Inside class, using root from Tkinter)

Tags: python, string, variables, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

```
from tkinter import *

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.plot = Canvas(master, width=500, height=120)
        self.plot.pack()

        self.1 = self.plot.create_text(10,10, text = "0")
        self.2 = self.plot.create_text(30,10, text = "0")
        self.3 = self.plot.create_text(50,10, text = "0")

        def txt_change(self,name,value):
            self.plot.itemconfigure(self.name, text=value)
```

So here I want to create just 1 function that can change the value of multiple variables by including a name. This name is however a string,but I want python to interpret the string as a variable name. I have 20 variables like this, and creating a new function for every variable doesn't look very clean. Is there a smart way to do this?

I was hoping that in the end I could use something like this: txt_change("1",20)

Comment: instead of `self.name` you should use `getattr( self, name )`

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper solution isn't to translate strings to variable names. Instead, store the items in a list or dictionary.

For example, this uses a dictionary:

```
class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        ...
        self.items = {}
        self.items[1] = self.plot.create_text(10,10, text = "0")
        self.items[2] = self.plot.create_text(30,10, text = "0")
        self.items[3] = self.plot.create_text(50,10, text = "0")

    def txt_change(self,name,value):
        item_id = self.items[name]
        self.plot.itemconfigure(item_id, text=value)

...
app=App(...)
app.txt_change(2, "this is the new text")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called `setattr()` in python:

```
>>> a = App(...)
>>> setattr(a, "name", "foo")
>>> a.name
"foo"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply's. I'm afraid that the text is not updated by the rootloop inside the Tkinter Canvas. I need to use the itemconfigure function. Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Create a function within your class using `setattr()` as:

```
def update_property(self, name, value):
    self.setattr(name, value)
```

Here, `name` is the class's `peoperty` and `value` is the value you want to set for the previosu property

Comment: Thanks for the reply's.
I'm afraid that the text is not updated by the rootloop inside the Tkinter Canvas. I need to use the itemconfigure function. Or am I doing something wrong?